# How to append html tag to textarea when press spesific key?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm trying to add a functionality to textarea which will add `<br>` tag to innerHTML of textarea when `Enter` is pressed.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/NWPooNO).

I've tried this with `texareaElement.val();` but it adds directly to textarea, but it shouldn't be seen by user. It should be on the background.

```js
function textAreaNewLine(element, event) {
  // 13 is the keycode for "enter" 
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var elVal = element.val();
    element.val(elVal + '<br>');
  }
}

$('#ta').on('keypress', function(event) {
  var el = $(this);
  textAreaNewLine(el, event);
  $('.main').html($('#ta').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ta"></textarea>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Why you want to add a `<br>` but want it not visible? What's the idea here? Break a line? Doesn't Enter do it by default?

Comment: On the textarea, Enter doesn't return line break.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting what you want here... you want to set value or return value from textArea? What is the purpose here? Can you [edit] the question to show what you expect as output after Enter is pressed? What you expect to see on the screen?

Comment: Try to add `"\n"` instead of `"<br>"` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You can add an empty line like:
Introduce another variable
var emptyLine = "\n";
and then append this to the value.

Check the fiddle below

```js
function textAreaNewLine(element, event) {
  // 13 is the keycode for "enter" 
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var elVal = element.val();
    var emptyLine = "\n";

    element.val(elVal + emptyLine );
  }
}

$('#ta').on('keypress', function(event) {
  var el = $(this);
  textAreaNewLine(el, event);
  $('.main').html($('#ta').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ta"></textarea>
<div class="main"></div>
```